# Can I understanding [Passing value in Python] this way?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

everybody, recently I 've read some articles about [passing value in Python].

here's the link: 
[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

However, I'm confusing if I can understand it this way?

[image]

As you see:

> 1. Outside the method():    ***the_link*** refs to the ***origin list obj***
> 2. Inside the method():
>
>    - copy a same new refs ***the_link(_copy)*** to the ***origin list obj***
>    - if there is a ***change_refs*** statement.
>    - then Python creates a ***new list obj*** inside the method.
>    - finally, it let ***the_list(_copy)*** refs to this ***new list obj***.
> 3. back to Outside: ***the_link*** still refs to the ***origin list obj***

if I consider it this way. The **OUTPUT** result is also the same.

But I'm not sure if this is **OK** or **NOT**?

Sorry that If I'm not expressing it correctly. Hope you guys understand = =

Comment: Create a practical example in code, and print the id (`print(id(the_list))`) every step along the way to see what's going on.

Comment: Upvote for the content of your list ;)  Try `the_list.append(['you', 'other', 'brothers', 'can\'t', 'deny'])`; this should fix your problem.

Comment: Is there a code example that comes with that diagram / steps?  It would really help clarify what you are not understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You got it correct. In Python, parameters are passed by what's called **reference value**, which means a copy or value of the reference (or pointer if you come from a C background) is passed to the method. Think of these references/pointers as integers containing indices to locations in memory.

Since the "copy" pointer (this is how we'll refer to it from now on) is pointing to the object that the "original" pointer was pointing to, any modifications we make to the object referenced by the "copy" pointer will be reflected in the original object, because the object referenced by the "copy" pointer *is* the original object.

But, since we have two different references (integers) pointing to the same object in memory (`original = XYZ location in memory` and `copy = XYZ location in memory`), when the *integral* or *location value* itself of the `copy` is changed (that is another object is assigned to `copy`), the change isn't reflected in `original` because `copy` and `original` are two separate references/pointers.

If, however, `copy` was a pointer to the pointer of the object (`ObjectType** copy`  in C), the change would have been reflected in the `original` pointer/reference too.

If we have the following program,

```
def mutate_list(copy):
    copy = [5, 6, 7, 8]
    print(original, copy)

original = [1, 2, 3, 4]
mutate_list(original)
```

The output will be `[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8]`

If we change the `mutate_list` method to the following:

```
def mutate_list(copy):
    copy.clear()
    copy.append([5, 6, 7, 8])
    print(original, copy)
```

The output would be `[5, 6, 7, 8] [5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the concept you are missing is "variable scope". Variables created inside a function/method are in a different scope as variables outside the function/method. They are different **even if they have the same name**. You create a variable called `the_list` that references an object then inside the method call you create another variable called 'the_list' that references another object. they are two different variables in different scopes.

Try visiting http://pythontutor.com/ to help you visualize what's going on.